# Could not stop an AsyncTask executing

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I could not stop my `AsyncTask` whatever i did; `cancel()`, put all work into while loop then break and more.

my task is about to  get/send data from a Mysql server.i know it's the worst way but this is my first try for android after had some steps in java.

So i want to execute and do all work and stop at the `onCreate()` before the layout shown.(before `setContentView()`). Because, if i hit a button that uses a data from database to fill a spinner may has not been downloaded yet.

I dont want to check my arraylist that i use to fill spinner if is it "null" cause of not working properly.

So if i can do that i can show up some warning about connection failure to the user.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

connect2 cnc=new connect2();
    cnc.execute();



    if (cnc.getStatus()==AsyncTask.Status.FINISHED)
    {
        setContentView(R.layout.window2);
    }


}

  private class connect2 extends AsyncTask<Void , Void, Void> {


    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

        try {

            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(a, b, c);
            PreparedStatement prs = conn.prepareStatement("select * from film , kategori,yonetmen where film.kategori_id=kategori.id and film.yonetmen_id=yonetmen.id");
            ResultSet rs = prs.executeQuery();
            PreparedStatement prs2 = conn.prepareStatement("select * from kategori ");
            ResultSet rs2 = prs2.executeQuery();
            PreparedStatement prs3 = conn.prepareStatement("select * from yonetmen ");
            ResultSet rs3 = prs3.executeQuery();

            while (rs.next()) {
                Kategori k = new Kategori(rs.getInt("kategori.id"), rs.getString("kategori.ad"));
                Yonetmen y = new Yonetmen(rs.getInt("yonetmen.id"), rs.getString("yonetmen.ad"));
                Film f = new Film(rs.getInt("id"), rs.getString("ad"), rs.getInt("sene"), k, y);
                ab.add(f);

            }
            rs.close();
            size = ab.size();
            while (rs2.next()) {
                Kategori k = new Kategori(rs2.getInt("kategori.id"), rs2.getString("kategori.ad"));
                ac.add(k);

            }
            rs2.close();
            while (rs3.next()) {
                Yonetmen k = new Yonetmen(rs3.getInt("yonetmen.id"), rs3.getString("yonetmen.ad"));
                ad.add(k);

            }
            rs3.close();

            switch (sw) {

                case 1:

                    StringBuilder cmd = new StringBuilder();
                    cmd.append("insert into film (ad,sene,yonetmen_id,kategori_id) values ('");
                    cmd.append(fa + "',");
                    cmd.append(ya + ",");
                    cmd.append(idy + ",");
                    cmd.append(idk + ")");
                    sw = 0;


                    try {
                        PreparedStatement sql = conn.prepareStatement(cmd.toString());
                        rslt = sql.executeUpdate();

                        conn.close();
                    } catch (SQLException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    break;

                case 2:


                    try {
                        PreparedStatement sql = conn.prepareStatement("delete from film where id=" + idy);
                        rslt2 = sql.executeUpdate();
                        sw = 0;

                        conn.close();
                    } catch (SQLException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    break;
                default:
                    break;

            }
            conn.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;


    } @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {

        list=ab;
        listk=ac;
        listy=ad;


        if (rslt==1) {


            AlertDialog.Builder builder1 = new AlertDialog.Builder( MainActivity.this);
            builder1.setMessage("Film Başarıyla Kaydedildi");
            builder1.setCancelable(true);

            builder1.setPositiveButton(
                    "Tamam",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            dialog.cancel();
                        }
                    });



            AlertDialog alert11 = builder1.create();
            alert11.show();
            rslt=0;

        }

        if (rslt2==1) {


            AlertDialog.Builder builder1 = new AlertDialog.Builder( MainActivity.this);
            builder1.setMessage("Silindi");
            builder1.setCancelable(true);

            builder1.setPositiveButton(
                    "Tamam",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            dialog.cancel();
                        }
                    });



            AlertDialog alert11 = builder1.create();
            alert11.show();
            rslt2=0;

        }

        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Implement like this. Try to break your code in parts, to check if is cancelled or not

```
doInBackground(){
   if(!isCancelled()){
     // few line of codes
   }else{
     return null;
   }
   if(!isCancelled()){
     // another few line of codes
   }else{
     return null;
   }
   if(!isCancelled()){
     // another few line of codes
   }else{
     return null;
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you,
but where shuld i call cancel() ?

Comment: @Gogo-the-Cat : you have to call that so that it returns true if it is cancelled

Comment: by the way you cant return a value if it is inside  a block.

Answer (score 0):

`AsyncTask.cancel()` doesn’t kill the Thread with no regard for the consequences. All it does is set the `AsyncTask` to a “cancelled” state. It’s up to the developer of `AsyncTask` to adhere cancel state in `doInBackground()`.